# Trackeback(most recent call last)

Tags: windows

I was writing a a code for calculating monthly salary and telling about job and i have an error visual studio told me that

Type error : can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Please tell me I'm learning I'm not a professional programmer

I was writing a a code for calculating monthly salary and telling about job and i have an errorvin vs code

Comment: Please share your code. Otherwise it's impossible for us to help you.